# Jenkins, pipline code to run branch indexing in multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I've got my Jenkins setup to run multibranch pipeline project where I use API to trigger specific branches in it.

my problem is that it only works if the branch was indexed, otherwise I get 404 from the API.

I have managed to run the branch indexing via the API, but I have no indication of when this task has been completed

by trail and error I have been able to figure out that:

- the API call to branch indexing does not return queue ID so I cannot check what its status
- the indexing task runs immediately, regardless of the queue and the executes limitation.
- I have been unable to run this task from pipeline (other job), trying to run this task results in error

is there any way to tell if the task has completed, and the success value of it?